# Other ways to disable Silverlight in IE 7?

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-7, installation

I know I can disable the Silverlight add-on using the Manage Add-ons dialog, but what other settings would cause Silverlight to not function and display the Install link, if the correct version of Silverlight is actually installed on the computer?

Silverlight applications do not display (they show the Install link) in Internet Explorer 7 on a single client's computer under one administrative user's account. They display in FireFox and Chrome on the same computer. They work for other users in Internet Explorer on the same computer. The add-on is enabled. It shows the same symptoms as if you disable the Silverlight add-on. What else could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Is Javascript enabled in IE? Is the site hosting the application in the Restricted Sites zone?

Comment: Javascript is enabled. The site is in the Trusted Sites list.